# (datetime.datetime.strptime) and not wanted 1900-01-01 date

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, strptime

I am trying to run a code that will calculate the difference between the current time and midnight, and the end output should print only in the "%H:%M:%S" format. it's running right, except it's also adding the 1900-01-01 date on the output. I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
import os
from datetime import date
from datetime import time
import datetime as dt

time_current = (str(dt.datetime.now().time()))
hour = (int(time_current[:-13]))
minute = (int(time_current[3:-10]))
second = (int(time_current[6:-7]))

new_hour = str(23 - hour)
new_minute = str(59 - minute)
new_second = str(59 - second)
new_time = (new_hour + ":" + new_minute + ":" + new_second)
time_left = dt.datetime.strptime(new_time,"%H:%M:%S")

print (time_left)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `datetime.datetime` object always has a date part.

If you want to only print the time part, just replace the last line with `print (time_left.time())`